# Applying an ngClass on only 1 element of a table in angular

Tags: html, angular, ng-class, angular-ngfor

In my table, I'm attempting to add a read more button to each row that has a paragraph. The button is displayed for each row, and when I click one, it operates concurrently for each row.

Here is my code:

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Text</th>
      <th scope="col">Date</th>
      <th scope="col">Comments</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let p of posts[0].posts">
      <div [ngClass]="{'limitTextHeight': isReadMore}">
        <td>{{p.post_text}}</td>
      </div>
      <button type="button" (click)="showText()" style="margin-top:15px">
        {{ isReadMore ? 'Read More': 'Read Less' }}
      </button>
      <td>{{p.post_date}}</td>
      <td>{{p.post_comments.length}} comment</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and my showText() function:

```
showText() {
    this.isReadMore = !this.isReadMore
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you're using single boolean variable i.e, `isReadMore` for all the looped `tr` tag.

What you can do is `posts[0].posts` map this `posts` with one more key that can be anything for example isReadMore in your case, then you will get unique instance to handle for each para, like this.
`{{ p?.isReadMore ? 'Read More': 'Read Less' }}`.
Hope you understood what I'm trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a common variable for all the rows. That's why when you click one they all change. You should use local ones, one for each row like so:

```
 <table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Text</th>
      <th scope="col">Date</th>
      <th scope="col">Comments</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let p of posts[0].posts">
      <div [ngClass]="{'limitTextHeight': isReadMore}">
        <td>{{p.post_text}}</td>
      </div>
      <button type="button" (click)="showText(p)" style="margin-top:15px">
        {{ p.isReadMore ? 'Read More': 'Read Less' }}
      </button>
      <td>{{p.post_date}}</td>
      <td>{{p.post_comments.length}} comment</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and the showText() function:

```
showText(post) {
    post.isReadMore = !post.isReadMore
 }
```

You could also add an *ngIf to check if there is text long enough before showing the button:

```
<button type="button" *ngIf="p.post_text?.length > 20" (click)="showText(p)" style="margin-top:15px">
    {{ p.isReadMore ? 'Read More': 'Read Less' }}
</button>
```